# Fetch only those record which do not have matching sum

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection as shown below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5c86633b897535539c1b36"),
    "studentId" : "dsdlkjafhiuelfdldahfiu",
    "marks" : [
        "subject" : "Physics",
        "sectionMap" : {
            "section_1" : {
                "scale" : 0,
                "unscaled" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "section_2" : {
                "scale" : 0,
                "unscaled" : NumberLong(10)
            }
        },
        "detailMap" : {
            "Mechanics" : {
                "scale" : 0,
                "unscaled" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "Optics" : {
                "scale" : 0,
                "unscaled" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "Fluid Mechanics" : {
                "scale" : 0,
                "unscaled" : NumberLong(5)
            }
        }, 
        ...
    ]
}
```

From the above collection, I want to fetch all the records for which the sum of `unscaled` values in `sectionMap` and that in `detailMap` is not the same. The number of entries in `sectionMap` and `detailMap` can change.

From all the examples that I looked up online all of them had fixed attribute names. Is there a way to group `sectionMap` and `detailMap` and compare them in the same query.

P.S. The mongo version I am using is 3.2.7

Comment: You need to upgrade your MongoDB to at least 3.4.4 to be able to use $objectToArray (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) any chances ?

Comment: Upgrading to MongoDB 3.4.4 will not be possible as other dependencies might be affected and would take longer time.